# How to configure a client server application in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, jakarta-ee, eclipse-plugin

I am working on a client server application which we used to start with requseting in IE with URL:http:\[ip of server]:[port no]. In this application client gets indication from server. Client is written in java and server in c++.

Client is build with ant and has the folder structure like inside the projet two subfolder is there one is named as client oyher one is library, both has the it's owin build.xml and build.properties file. AND CLIENT CONTAINS ALL THE JARS THAT LIBRARY HAS.

I tried to configure it in latest version of eclipse JUNO but getting errors.

Kindly guide me to configure it, so that i can debug the client code... Thanks in Advance

Comment: What are the errors you get?

Comment: @shazin 1. httpservlet cannot resolve to a type 2.   cannot resolve to a type 3.HelpSet  cannot resolve to a type.... This error comes when i try it to configure with existing ant build and i gave the build.xml path of client

Answer (score 0):

Try to configure it as file system, because you have 2folders containing source code. If you are adding one another will be creating problem.

Comment: Could you please give the details of it. I tried to add it as you said... I went NEW->OTHER->GENRAL->FOLDER but it is asking for parent folder? what should I do about it? path of project is not working...